# Using Blueprint CSS with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, blueprint-css

I am using Blueprint CSS with Rails. Whenever I use a `a tag with a href value`, the value in the href shows in the html page.

For example
`<a href="google.com">Google</a>` 
gets displayed as Google(google.com).

This is the generated HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample Screen</title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css?1285799042" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css?1285799042" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1288165422" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1288165422" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1288165422" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1288165422" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1288165422" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1290278728" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="LYQJCGVJThsPuRw/CLlxwYvDd4OKUICerFevQsmo0wc="/>
</head>
<body class="showgrid">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="google.com">Google</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this

Comment: Not sure whether this has anything to do with Blueprint or Rails. Can you show the finished HTML code? You are aware that there is a quote missing in your link?

Comment: Thanks Pekka. I added the missing quote and added a sample screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix for this problem is by setting the media attribute's value to print in the print.css stylesheet tag.

For example

```
 <link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```